# Is this transistor schematic of a CMOS layout correct?

Tags: transistors, cmos

Working through some problem sets on CMOS circuits right now, is the following circuit correct?

It seems eerily close to a 3 input NAND circuit, except that the top three transistors I’ve drawn are all nmos. Or are they supposed to be PMOS? Unfortunately the picture included is as is, and there is no other information.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are almost certainly right, this is a 3-input NAND, and the parallel transistors leading to Vdd are PMOS.  Having all the transistors be NMOS would provide no connection to Vdd unless the input were higher than Vdd, and in that case setting the inputs all high would result in a direct short from Vdd to GND.

Comment: Thanks! Since there is no distinguishing feature on the given diagram, does that mean that this must be assumed (say, if one were already acquainted with the 3-input NAND design)? Or is there actually a way to figure this out, maybe a feature on the diagram that I am not familiar with?

Comment: I didn't see any notations indicating the doping of various regions, but your schematic looked correct for the NAND and useless for any other assumption.  I've probably looked at a lot more schematics and layouts than you have (I'm old) so I came to the same conclusion as you, but with more confidence.

Comment: Nice, thank you for the confirmation!

Comment: Any tips for future problems? Should I just keep iterating and getting experience, as some CMOS layouts can come without notations like the one I came across?

Comment: Go with your gut until it stops making sense, and when you're wrong, understand why.  :)